# How to interprete OpenCover console output

Tags: .net, opencover, gitlab-ci

I want to use OpenCover with gitlab ci which allows to extrace a single value from the build output to show a coverage figure.

I get the following output from opencover

```
  Visited Classes 132 of 310 (42.58)
  Visited Methods 876 of 2679 (32.7)
  Visited Points 7044 of 21918 (32.14)
  Visited Branches 2168 of 9670 (22.42)

  ==== Alternative Results (includes all methods 
     including those without corresponding source) ====
  Alternative Visited Classes 148 of 332 (44.58)
  Alternative Visited Methods 1043 of 3150 (33.11)
```

I haven't found a source describing how I should interpret these values. So far I assume this.

- Classes - The classes which are covered at least a little
- Methods - The methods which are covered at least a little
- Points - The lines of code which are covered
- Branches - The compiled lines which are covered (but that is just a wild guess)
- Alternative results - Well, I suppose this includes third party classes / methods that are covered (I haven't tweaked my filter yet). But as this value is only slighly higher than original value, I guess this would exclude all framework classes.

So basically my question is

a) am I right about my guesses and if not, what is the right explanation.
b) what's the best value to choose for an overall coverage result?

For now I would use `Visited Points` because (if I am right about my guess) this will tell me the level of my source code lines which are covered.

Comment: Do you use OpenCover on gitlab.com? Can you please share - how did you configure the `.gitlab-ci.yml` for running it? Thank you

Comment: @Jenan Unfortunately I am using a private gitlab instance but I am planning to create a sample project on gitlab.com for demo purpose. My gitlab-ci.yml is very lightweight cause I use FAKE as a build tool.

Comment: OK, thank you for reply. I think it doesn't work on gitlab.com, because there is not probable windows machine.

Comment: @Jenan you can use your own runner even on gitlab.com, even your dev machine. I belive runners poll on the gitlab server instance, so no need to configure your firewall. And, depending on your project, you could try building your app with mono or net core inside docker.

Answer (score 0):

These numbers are just a quick summary of the coverage. For full details you should use the data that is emitted in the XML that is outputted as part of the operation. For best results use [ReportGenerator](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ReportGenerator) (as recommended) to get a detailed HTML report.

Comment: Actually I am using ncrunch for testing and coverage. I just wanto to integrate OpenCover to store a single value and see how the coverage evolves over time - https://about.gitlab.com/2014/10/22/gitlab-ci-5-dot-1-released/

For detailed coverage I would look at NCrunch again

Comment: I'd still extract the number in the XML